# Freeze bower package version numbers

Tags: javascript, bower, bower-install

In Python, when using `pip freeze`, you usually get the full version number frozen:

```
# requirements.txt
patsy==0.2.1
pelican==3.3
pika==0.9.13
Pillow==2.4.0
prettytable==0.7.2
prettytime==0.0.2
py==1.4.20
```

However, I've noticed with `bower.json` created using `--save` that doesn't seem to always be the case:

```
"angular-touch": "1.3.0",
"angular-ui-utils": "bower",
"angular-bootstrap": "~0.11.0",
"angular-ui-router": null,
"venturocket-angular-slider": null,
"css-toggle-switch": null,
"ngprogress": null,
"ng-tags-input": "2.0.1",
"angular-growl-v2": null,
"ng-file-upload": null,
```

This causes problems when, for example, we onboard a new developer who runs `bower install` and then gets a different version of e.g. `ng-file-upload` than current members of the team have, with breaking changes, and no one realizes.

Is there a command to completely freeze my current list of bower packages?

Comment: Well you can just edit `bower.json` manually to do so. A command to do so for deployment still hasn't been implemented yet: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/505